# How to delete duplicate array in javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, unique

Array

```
[ li.size30x30, li.size60x30, li.size60x30, li.size30x30, li.size60x30,
  li.size60x30, li.size60x30, li.size60x30, li.size30x30, 704 more… ]
```

expect result Array `[ li.size30x30, li.size60x30 ]`

Comment: I really liked this: [unique] (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60128/removing-duplicates-from-an-array-quickly), it's elegant(look at the first answer)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** and **[`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)** here

```js
var arrayEl = ['li.size30x30', 'li.size60x30', 'li.size60x30', 'li.size30x30', 'li.size60x30',
  'li.size60x30', 'li.size60x30', 'li.size60x30', 'li.size30x30'
];

arrayEl = arrayEl.filter(function(v, i, arr) {
  return i == arr.indexOf(v);
  // checking array element already occured before the element using indexOf(), which returns index of first occurance 
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(arrayEl));
```